# Managing panels (GridLayout) size in a BorderLayout JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, border-layout

So, i'm making a java battleship game with a GUI from Java Swing. I actually designed the borders (a very initial way) and now i'm trying to make a well-sized board. Consider that the board are the blue/red panels in the photo below

[A pack() results in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeYpS.png)

[fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEYHo.png)

But i want larger boards. What should i do? setPrefferedSize() seems to not solve the problem, i think because the JFrame is BorderLayout...

```
package testeborderlayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class TesteBorderLayout extends JFrame {
    private JButton[][] tabuleiro1 = new JButton[10][10];
    private JButton[][] tabuleiro2 = new JButton[10][10];
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private JPanel jPanel2;
    private JTextField jTextField1; 
    
    public TesteBorderLayout() {
        initComponents();
    }
                       
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new JPanel();
        jTextField1 = new JTextField();
        
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<10;j++){
                tabuleiro1[i][j]=new JButton();
                tabuleiro2[i][j]=new JButton();
            }
        }
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new Color(255, 102, 102));
        jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new Color(51, 102, 255));
        jPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
        getContentPane().add(jPanel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
                jPanel1.add(tabuleiro1[i][j]);
                jPanel2.add(tabuleiro2[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        jTextField1.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        jTextField1.setText("Comandos para o usuário");
        getContentPane().add(jTextField1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setTitle("Batalha Naval");
        pack();
    }                

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TesteBorderLayout().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
                
}
```

Comment: The CENTER of a `BorderLayout` is the region that expands when you maximize the `JFrame`.  Create one `JPanel` with a `GridLayout` to hold both player grids and put the `JTextField` either on PAGE_START or PAGE_END,

Comment: *"i want larger boards."* Use bigger components in them. It is using buttons? A button can be made larger in a number of ways (some more useful than others, depending on the context). The ways (off the top of my head): larger font, longer text, HTML content (with CSS for padding), larger icon *or* larger margin. It might also appear in a panel or layout that will provide an empty border around it.

Answer (score 1):

`BorderLayout.PAGE_START/END` will use the components `preferredSize`.  Instead, I'd use a `GridBagLayout`, for example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new TesteBorderLayout();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TesteBorderLayout extends JFrame {
        private JButton[][] tabuleiro1 = new JButton[10][10];
        private JButton[][] tabuleiro2 = new JButton[10][10];
        private JPanel jPanel1;
        private JPanel jPanel2;
        private JTextField jTextField1;

        public TesteBorderLayout() {
            initComponents();
        }

        private void initComponents() {

            jPanel1 = new JPanel();
            jPanel2 = new JPanel();
            jTextField1 = new JTextField();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    tabuleiro1[i][j] = new JButton();
                    tabuleiro2[i][j] = new JButton();
                }
            }

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            jPanel1.setBackground(new Color(255, 102, 102));
            jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
            contentPane.add(jPanel1, gbc);

            jPanel2.setBackground(new Color(51, 102, 255));
            jPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            contentPane.add(jPanel2, gbc);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    jPanel1.add(tabuleiro1[i][j]);
                    jPanel2.add(tabuleiro2[i][j]);
                }
            }

            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weighty = 0;

            jTextField1.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            jTextField1.setText("Comandos para o usuário");
            contentPane.add(jTextField1, gbc);

            add(contentPane);
            setTitle("Batalha Naval");
            pack();
        }
    }    
}
```

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: I tested here, and i think i've got a nice result :) But, do you have any tip to emphasis the board color (blue/red)? Just in a way to be right visible, like a border or something... Its not really necessary, but would be cool.
Big thank you!

Comment: You could use a `EmptyBorder` or a `LineBorder` or a `CompositeBorder`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the contentPange you need to make it visible. Also pack() always makes the minimum possible dimensions. You should replace the pack with the following two lines.

```
    this.setSize(800, 800);
    getContentPane().setVisible(true);
```

Then you can see how you want to resize the individual components. (panels, buttons etc)